# Matplotlib - Creating plot for black background presentation slides

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm successfully using Python and Matplotlib to create transparent PNG figures that look good when I add the plots to a Powerpoint slide that has a white background. Below is an example:

[image]

However, when I use a **presentation slide deck that has a black background**, the figure does not look as good. The text font and lines are all black, and they blend right into the background.

[image]

Is there a quick and easy way to generate these figures so that they will look good on a black slide? For example, I'd like to quickly make all the lines and text white. I know I can individually set the colors for the title, axis labels, axis values, etc., but is there a "master theme" for quickly making this kind of change?

Here is what my code generally looks like:

```
_ = plt.bar(hours, series_two, label='One')
_ = plt.bar(hours, series_one, label='Two')
_ = plt.grid()
_ = plt.xticks(range(0,24))
_ = plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.05))
_ = plt.ylim(0, 1.0)
_ = plt.xlabel('Hour of day')
_ = plt.ylabel('Value')
_ = plt.tight_layout()
_ = plt.title('Experimental results')
_ = plt.legend()
_ = plt.show()
```

EDIT: I used `plt.style.use("dark_background")` from the related questions, but the results look terrible. I just want to change the lines and text, not the colors of the bars.

[image]

Comment: Those are not exact duplicates, but the solution is clearly to change the style to `dark_background`, as shown in both of them.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thanks. Those other two questions have relevant answers, but the titles of the questions are unrelated to "dark background". That is why I could not find them.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I updated the question with the "dark backgorund" style, but the results look terrible. So the answers to the other questions did not answer mine.

Comment: Fine, in that case please clearly state how the different parts of the plots should look like and in how far setting the respective rcParams do not help.

Comment: How about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43000500/change-pyplot-axes-text-color-to-white

Answer (score 23):

If the predesigned [`dark_background` style](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/style_sheets/dark_background.html) does not match the expectations, one may set the respective rcParams manually. The following might produce the desired plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams.update({
    "lines.color": "white",
    "patch.edgecolor": "white",
    "text.color": "black",
    "axes.facecolor": "white",
    "axes.edgecolor": "lightgray",
    "axes.labelcolor": "white",
    "xtick.color": "white",
    "ytick.color": "white",
    "grid.color": "lightgray",
    "figure.facecolor": "black",
    "figure.edgecolor": "black",
    "savefig.facecolor": "black",
    "savefig.edgecolor": "black"})

x = range(1,25)
y = range(60,108)[::-2]
y2 = range(16,40)[::-1]

plt.bar(x, y,  label='One')
plt.bar(x, y2, label='Two')
plt.grid()
plt.xticks(x)

plt.xlabel('Hour of day')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('Experimental results', color="w")
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that you would need to set the title color manually, because the default text color is set to black, such that the legend text is black. Else, one could of course do the inverse and set the legend text color manually.

Comment: This is great having all the parameters in one answer. Thank you.

Comment: the plot background color (background behind the bars) is missing..

Comment: @alexzander If you want a black background for the axes, set 'axes.facecolor' to black. The answer has it set to white. You might find that the choice of colors doesn't show up well over black and that `plt.style.use("dark_background")` actually works better in many cases.

Comment: yea that one works. also you can use `plt.style.use('Solarize_Light2')`, its very warm and healthy for eyes.